# need to un-check a checkbox as soon as it is checked. Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

i have an object array with a Boolean property bound to a check box

plunkr 
https://plnkr.co/edit/j25nOhYm1MNeJzUJzBBs

```
 this.data =  [{ "name":"Ford", "selected":false},
    { "name":"BMW","selected":false },
    { "name":"Fiat","selected":false }
]
```

in html i tried ngModel and ngModelChange

```
  <li *ngFor="let item of data;">
    <input class="checkbox binning-checkbox" type="checkbox"  
    (ngModelChange)="select(item)" [(ngModel)]="item.selected">
   {{ item.name}}
  </li>
```

i have also tried [checked] and (change)

```
  <li *ngFor="let item of data;">
    <input class="checkbox binning-checkbox" type="checkbox"  
    (change)="select(item)" [checked]="item.selected">
   {{ item.name}}
  </li>
```

also tried

```
<div>
<li *ngFor="let item of data;">
    <input class="checkbox binning-checkbox" type="checkbox" (change)="select(item)" [(ngModel)]="item.selected"> {{ item.name}}
</li>
```

**updated the plunkr** 
but the event code

```
 public select(item){
alert(item.selected );
item.selected = false;  }
```

is unable to "de-select" the checkbox

Comment: What is the point of unchecking a checkbox immediately after it is checked? Can you give a use case for this?

Comment: in the original code when the max number of checkbox are checked i want to uncheck the last one checked.

Comment: feels like that when the max number of checked is reached you want to make all others disabled

Comment: item.selected is always false in your example... no matter if you select an item or not.

Comment: yes thats whats happening in one example if you see the plunkr.

Comment: made an update to plunkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'hack' this with `setTimeout`, which will just a tinytinty time later set the checkbox to false :)

```
public select(item){
  setTimeout(() => {
    item.selected = false;
  })
}
```

in your sample demo, I used the `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` version: https://plnkr.co/edit/53Tb6wiXYAlat52VPuwG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the object to keep the selected status, change the array to

```
this.data =  ["Ford","BMW","Fiat"]

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of data">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"
        ng-model="xyx"
        ng-click="toggleItem(item)"
        ng-checked="selectedItems.indexOf(item) > -1"
        ng-required="selectedItems.length == 0" /> 
        {{item}}</label>
  </li>                  
</ul>

toggleItem(item){
    var index = this.selectedItems.indexOf(item);
    if(index == -1) {
      this.selectedItems.push(animal);
    }
    else{
      this.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

See the working [demo here](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1222/angularjs-checkboxlist-required-validation-with-demo)

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to use ngModel with change event along with click event

```
[(ngModel)]="item.selected" (change)="select(dataItem,$event)" (click)="checkExceed($event,dataItem)"
```

on the click when total number of attempts are greater than x i simply use

```
$event.preventDefault();
```